MySQL Output Redirection only output blank lines
I inherited this bash script from previous admin which takes input from a CSV file. I am modifying it to output the output and error message to a text file. However, I am getting an output file with blank lines only. Would like to ask if anyone know why it is behaving this way.  Thanks in advance for your help.
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do

configname=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f1)
servicename=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2)
oldcommand=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f3)
newcommand=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f4)

part1=$(echo -e "SELECT config_name,service_description,check_command FROM tbl_service")
part2=$(echo -e "WHERE config_name='$configname' and check_command='$newcommand' and service_description='$servicename'")

sqlquery=$(echo -e "$part1 $part2")

echo "$sqlquery"

output=$(echo "$sqlquery;" | mysql --host=localhost --user=sqluser --password='sqlpwd' sqldb1)
echo "$output" > Output.log 2> Error.log


done < "$1"

I'm not sure what is wrong with this script and why it's outputting blank lines.

What's with all the var=$(echo blah)?  And especially, what's with capturing the standard output (only) of the mysql command, only to output it?  And what makes you think that echo "$output" would produce any output to its standard error that would be of any interest?

Also, note that your output and error logs are clobbered on every iteration of the loop, and that you have no validation at all. At best you'll get the output of the last query, but note that if, say, the last query yields 0 rows, maybe because the last line in the file is blank, then the final .log files will be empty.

The above provides a possible explanation for the behavior you're asking about, but we can't tell you for sure without example input, including database data.  Possibly the terminal output of the original version of the script would suffice for conveying the relevant database content.

Additionally, the script presented outputs the queries themselves in addition to their results, but it captures only the results.  Is this intentional?

As John mentioned, there are a couple issues with this script. I think the biggest issue is that the error output from the mysql command is not going to show up in the "Error.log" file since the error output isn't captured from the mysql command itself. I would recommend not setting the "output" variable to the output of the mysql command, but instead doing the following:
echo "$sqlquery;" | mysql --host=localhost --user=sqluser --password='sqlpwd' sqldb1 >> Output.log 2>> Error.log

Note, that I also have it append to the files, as opposed to truncating them for each run. This is important, since the invocation of mysql is in a loop and therefore the only thing that could be possible be in either of the files would be from the last run and not from all the runs.
Having said all this, here's an alternative to the script:
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do

  configname=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f1)
  servicename=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2)
#  oldcommand=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f3)  # Never used.
  newcommand=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f4)

  sqlquery="SELECT config_name,service_description,check_command FROM tbl_service WHERE config_name='$configname' and check_command='$newcommand' and service_description='$servicename'"

  echo "$sqlquery"   # Not really sure the purpose of this line.
  echo "$sqlquery" >> Output.log

  echo "$sqlquery;" | mysql --host=localhost --user=sqluser --password='sqlpwd' sqldb1 >> Output.log 2>> Error.log

done < "$1"

Note that I changed out all the variable=$(echo -e "some string with other variables") to just variable="some string with another variables". The -e option does cause "echo" to interpret certain sequence of characters to output control characters, but I don't see how any of those would be used here so I got rid of them.
You might also note that I added a echo "$sqlquery" >> Output.log since I didn't know what good it did to just output that string to standard out, and I could see adding it to the file, so you could tell when each run began. Obviously, feel free to take that out if not wanted.

Hi Cloudlady,  thanks for the reply.

I tried using just the var sqlquery by combining what was in the vars part1 and part2 but it ended up with the commands before "WHERE" getting concatenated instead. That's how  that sqlquery = echo $part1 $part2 came about.

what this script is doing is to go to table tbl_service, get the values in columns config_name, service_description and check_commands that matches the value of vars configname, newcommand and servicename.
these values are read from a text file that contains lines where each line have values separated by comma. The purpose of this script is to replace current check commands with the update check commands.

This script is actually running correctly as all the values have been updated. The challenge is we need to verify each of the lines manually and with thousands of lines, that will take significant amount of time.

My apologies, this script is the reporting script. I was explaining about the UPDATE script in my earlier comment.

Since we have approx 35,000 of check commands in total, i want to use the same list that we used for the UPDATE script to extract only those check commands which i will then import into excel for better processing.
my thinking is i would select the items from the columns containing the values and export it to a text file. however, this is not happening. as i am new to mysql, i am checking here if someone can explain to me what is wrong.
I am thinking of completely overhauling these scripts but i can't do it until i fully understand the problem it has.

How do you "verify each of the lines"? Also, you mentioned "this is not happening." Are you saying your sql query isn't getting you the information you are looking for? Can you provide the exact select statement you are using? As well as the output, if any?

My intention in sharing this script which i inherited from previous admin is to understand the "correct way" to write a script for this purpose.

The problem is, I'm not really sure what the end goal is script is. If you just need all the lines from the tbl_service table that have the configure_name, service_description and check_name that match the other file, the SQL statement you have does that, except I would change it to select * FROM tbl_service WHERE config_name='$configname' and check_command='$newcommand' and service_description='$servicename' that way you'd get all the fields from each line in the tbl_service table that has those values. Otherwise, it is just going to each those three fields for each match.

So, I'm willing to help, but I need to understand what the end goal here is.
